# Installing google app engine plugin eclipse juno

Tags: google-app-engine, eclipse-juno

Does Eclipse juno require to have a Java EE environment pre installed to install the GAE plugin?

like everyone i get error like this

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
      Software being installed: Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.2 3.4.2.v201310081840-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e42.feature.feature.group
3.4.2.v201310081840-rel-r42)
      Missing requirement: Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.2 3.4.2.v201310081840-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e42.feature.feature.group
3.4.2.v201310081840-rel-r42) requires 'org.eclipse.wst.css.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your juno releases first.
1. Then go to help-> Install new software. 
Add -> this link and name it GAE .  https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2

1. Now you will see some packages with checkbox. select Google plugin for app engine and SDK's.

3.Click finish and now your eclipse will download and install the needed packages.

Then you will find Google->web application project in Create new project menu.